# How can I get tkinter checkbox not to write to a file when left unchecked

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
Lab = Tk()

Lab.title("Lab department")
Lab.geometry("400x200+200+100")

nameLabel = Label(Lab, text="First name: ",font="Aerial 10")
nameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

name_entry = Entry(Lab, width=20)
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

#create upt test checkbox to select the test
uptVar = StringVar()

upt = Checkbutton(Lab, text="U.P.T ",variable=uptVar, onvalue="UPT", offvalue="")
upt.deselect()
upt.grid(row=1, column=0)

#a label for upt results selction
upt_label = Label(Lab, text="UPT Results ", font="Aerial 10")
upt_label.grid(row=1, column=1)

    # the dropdown menu for upt results
uptResults = ["Positive",
              "Negative"]

uptresult_Var = StringVar()
uptresult_Var.set(uptResults[0])

upt_checkbox = OptionMenu(Lab, uptresult_Var, *uptResults)
upt_checkbox.grid(row=

1, column=2)


preg = "UPT"

def upt_clients():
    fullname = name_entry.get()
        
    preg_details = fullname + " " + uptVar.get() +" "+  uptresult_Var.get() + "\n"
    with open(preg, "a") as pregFile:
        pregFile.write(preg_details)
        pregFile.close()
            

uptButton = Button(Lab, text="upt record",command=upt_clients)
uptButton.grid(row=1, column=3)
```

`am working with tkinter checkbox, I want  to write to a file when the box is checked.

what I cant get is, not to write to a file when the box is left unchecked.
any help to pass that

Comment: What all have you tried so far?

Comment: Please take the time to properly format the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I think what you are trying to accomplish is:
If the checkbox 'U.P.T' is checked you want to append data to the file defined by variable preg
If the check box is unchecked you don't want to append to the file.

Given that the above is your goal, there are a couple of issues with your code as shown.

1. you need to add a statement `Lab.mainloop()` at the end to cause the Lab window to display.
2. you need to add a test of the checkbox status before attempting to write to the file.
3. you need to declare uptVar, uptresult_Var as global variables in the main method and within the subfunction upt_clients.

Here is the updated code which incorporates these changes:

```
from tkinter import *
global uptVar, uptresult_Var
Lab = Tk()

Lab.title("Lab department")
Lab.geometry("400x200+200+100")

nameLabel = Label(Lab, text="First name: ",font="Aerial 10")
nameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

name_entry = Entry(Lab, width=20)
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

#create upt test checkbox to select the test
uptVar = StringVar()

upt = Checkbutton(Lab, text="U.P.T ",variable=uptVar, onvalue="UPT", offvalue="")
upt.deselect()
upt.grid(row=1, column=0)

#a label for upt results selction
upt_label = Label(Lab, text="UPT Results ", font="Aerial 10")
upt_label.grid(row=1, column=1)

    # the dropdown menu for upt results
uptResults = ["Positive",
              "Negative"]

uptresult_Var = StringVar()
uptresult_Var.set(uptResults[0])

upt_checkbox = OptionMenu(Lab, uptresult_Var, *uptResults)
upt_checkbox.grid(row= 1, column=2)


preg = "UPT"

def upt_clients():
    global uptVar, uptresult_Var
    fullname = name_entry.get()        
    preg_details = fullname + " " + uptVar.get() +" "+  uptresult_Var.get() + "\n"  
    if uptVar.get():
        with open(preg, "a") as pregFile:
            pregFile.write(preg_details)
            pregFile.close()
            
uptButton = Button(Lab, text="upt record",command=upt_clients)
uptButton.grid(row=1, column=3) 
Lab.mainloop()
```